# How to receive my data from my raspberry pi and show them in a web app

Tags: http, flask, webserver

I have a program on the raspberry pi that collects data from the car via obd connection, this program starts automatically when the raspberry pi is started, as soon as the program ends, these data are automatically saved in a .csv file. What I want to do now is to make an online web application to which the data will be sent every time a new .csv file with data is created and display it there. I also want to have an interface through this web program with which I can start and stop the program that collects the data from the car. I would like you to explain to me how I can do this and what codes I will need to have from both the raspberry side and the web app side?

I think that flask will be the best option for that as soon as the program is written on python.

Answer (score 0):

For sending the data from the RPi, you need just a URL and the data. The URL should be something like `http://<server_address>`, where `<server_address>` is either the domain name of the server (e.g. `my_server.com`) or the static IP (`127.0.0.1:8000`). Also, if you want to start and stop the program, you are going to need Your code should look like this

```
#Do other imports that you need
import requests

#Your code here

csv = "mycsv.csv"
url = "http//:<address>"
files = {'upload_file': open(csv,'rb')}

requests.post(url, files=files)
```

I suggest you to send JSON files, though, because it is used more often in web applications and APIs.

For starting and stoping the program remotely, you can use a python app that gets a request from the server and uses bash commands, in order to start and stop the other program. The code should look like this:

```
import os

url = "http://<address>"
flag = None

while True:
    response = requests.get(url)  # Blocks and waits for the server to send the flag
    flag = int(response.text)
    if bool(flag):  # The server send 1
        os.system("python3 <path>")
    if not bool(flag):  # The server send 0
        os.system("sudo kill -9 <process id>")
```

You could use multithreading, instead of a second program. Instead of using commands, you can use locks. But, the logic is the same.

For the server side, well...

There are lots of things to do. Indeed Flask is good choice, since it is a lightweight and simple framework, given that what you need is also quite simple. I can't give you the whole code, since that's not the what stack overflow is about. But, there are lots of resources and support from the community for many topics around Flask, so you should be fine. The main idea of your server is that you want to GET the data, POST the flag and display the data in your computer somehow. Each one is an endpoint, with its own functionality. For displaying the data, you have to create an html file that prints the data (you can use Jinja to import python code inside html and css for style). You would also need a database, since sending and recieving the whole file all the time is time and space consuming.

That's what I'm thinking, given the description of the problem. I hope you find what you want.